# Git archived repository as a full functional repository?

Tags: git, archive

I need to setup a git repository on a place that has restrictions on the filetypes and contents. Of course, that could become a pain for synchronizing so I could overcome that limitation by archiving the repository.

However, archiving the repository would make the archive to be just that: an archive or a file without repository posibilities.

**I wonder, is there any way to make git interact with an archived repository** (let's say, a .zip file) **as a full functional repository**, with the only difference that it is contained in a different file system structure?

I would love to be able to do something like this, if possible at all:

```
git clone /myRepo /otherlocation/repo.zip
# myRepo is a directory with all the files
# repo.zip is a compressed zip file
# could git treat both as repositories anyway -- any approach?
```

I would like to be able to perform other clones, pushes and pulls to this archive, as a way to sync different local repositories with this restricted location I have.

**Background**:

I need to work on a project and I haven't been given any place to host my repositories. For the moment, I'm working with a local copy of a git repository I created, but I would like to have that synced in a real server. As I haven't been given any place to put my code, I am thinking in using a Sharepoint folder for documentation regarding the project. Sharepoint does provide limitations on the type of files I can post to it, and I can have the server set up so I can access it's document library as an UNC path.

However, I can overcome the filetypes limitation by archiving everything into a .zip file and uploading it. Instead of doing all of that manually every time, I would like to see if git (or anything else) can take care of that for me.

Comment: This could probably done with a commit hook that zips up and uploads the repository whenever you commit - see http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: What kind of operating system are you using? Why can't you use `git archive` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Wouldn't that remove my history? Exploring your option I found about `git bundle`, which I didn't know about. Would you suggest that as an option as well?

Comment: Does it have to be an on-premise file server? You could easily push your code to a free, private, bit bucket repository.

Comment: @RyanRinaldi In this case, yes, because this is code a company I work for owns and should still have if I happen to leave or suddenly die. However, that seems a good solution when that's not the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would periodically (perhaps once a week) `git bundle` your local repository and put the resulting file somewhere on the sharepoint server. I would make each bundle a full repository and keep the last couple as backups too keep things simple, rather than using `git bundle`'s incremental features.